is it possible to shedule jobs in multiple databases in laravel?
I want to build an app that can schedule and run jobs across multiple databases but when I specify the database connection in the handle method, it only dispatches jobs to a single database
i have specified the database connection in my model
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Draft extends Model
{
protected $guarded=[];
    protected $connection = 'mysql';
}

here is my handle method
class Draft implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;


    public $task;
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function handle(): void
    {
        \App\Models\Draft::create([
            "value"=> $this->task,
        ]);
    }
}


here is my routes/console file
<?php

use App\Jobs\Draft;
use App\Jobs\TaskJob;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schedule;
Artisan::command('inspire', function () {
    $this->comment(Inspiring::quote());
})->purpose('Display an inspiring quote')->hourly();

Schedule::job(new TaskJob())->everyThirtySeconds();
Schedule::job(new Draft())->everyThirtySeconds();

here a my two mysql database connections
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for database operations. This is
    | the connection which will be utilized unless another connection
    | is explicitly specified when you execute a query / statement.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlite'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Below are all of the database connections defined for your application.
    | An example configuration is provided for each database system which
    | is supported by Laravel. You're free to add / remove connections.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DB_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DB_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4'),
            'collation' => env('DB_COLLATION', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'),
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],


        'link' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DB_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_LINK', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_LINK', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_LINK', 'laravel'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_LINK', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_LINK', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4'),
            'collation' => env('DB_COLLATION', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'),
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'mariadb' => [
            'driver' => 'mariadb',
            'url' => env('DB_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4'),
            'collation' => env('DB_COLLATION', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'),
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DB_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'search_path' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DB_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            // 'encrypt' => env('DB_ENCRYPT', 'yes'),
            // 'trust_server_certificate' => env('DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'false'),
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run on the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => [
        'table' => 'migrations',
        'update_date_on_publish' => true,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer body of commands than a typical key-value system
    | such as Memcached. You may define your connection settings here.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],

];


From what I can see, Draft model has only one connection defined, that is: protected $connection = 'mysql';

sorry about that i actully have two mysql database connection, let me edit the question

I'm not sure I understand your question properly. Do you want to create the same scheduled task in the queue table in multiple databases? Or do you want to create the Draft model, in the Drafts table in multiple databases, but only handled by the main queue worker?

i think i have solve the issue.
initially, I wanted to have a jobs table in multiple databases linked to the same application. since I was unable to dispatch queues to multiple databases, I dispatched all my queues to my default database while specifying the database connection. when I ran a php artisan queue:work, it executed all queues in their respective databases.
